# Django form field in if statement fail

Tags: python, django

I'm rendering a Django form using an if statement to construct the html template:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {% if field.name == 'user_name' or 'phone' or 'email' or 'password1' %}
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <p class="text-left m-0 fs-13">{{ field.label_tag }}</p>
      {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
    </div>
  {% else %}
    bla bla
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But when I call the template, all fields are constructed using the if statement code, but I have fields like: location, birth_date... that are True in the else statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused about your problem.  Is the issue that you are rendering something like `location` even though you don't want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you could do:

```
if field.name in ['user_name', 'phone', 'email', 'password1']:
```

However you can’t define a list in the Django template, so you would have to do the more verbose:

```
{% if field.name == 'user_name' or field.name == 'phone' or field.name == 'email' or field.name == 'password1' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
{% if field.name == 'user_name' or 'phone' or 'email' or 'password1' %}
```

not be

```
{% if field.name in ['user_name', 'phone', 'email', 'password1'] %}
```

Off the top of my head I would assume

```
or 'phone'
```

to evaluate to true.